# Retrieving Data objects from Child in Firebase Android For a Logged in User

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to retrieve just the child data from here but when i debug it shows null on each object, I'm not sure why, please help.
I've followed some instructions here on Stack overflow but i can't seem to get a solution.

My data on firebase looks like this:

[image: Image of the firebase db]

Here is my code:

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("the-root-db");
            DatabaseReference mFirebaseDbReferenceCurrentUser = dbRef.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
            DatabaseReference userSettingTable = mFirebaseDbReferenceCurrentUser.child("UserSetting");
            userSettingTable.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot userSettingFromDb : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            mDbPrice = (String) userSettingFromDb.child("currencyPrice").getValue();
                            mDbCurrencyId = (String) userSettingFromDb.child("currencyId").getValue();
                            mDbUserTrackPrice = (String) userSettingFromDb.child("userSettingCurrencyValue").getValue();
                            break;
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d("Query Db", databaseError.toString());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're attaching a `ValueListener` to a specific node, you will get a `DataSnapshot` with only that node. This means you don't need to loop over its children.

```
userSettingTable.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mDbPrice = dataSnapshot.child("currencyPrice").getValue(String.class);
        mDbCurrencyId = dataSnapshot.child("currencyId").getValue(String.class);
        mDbUserTrackPrice = dataSnapshot.child("userSettingCurrencyValue").getValue(String.class);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did as per your suggestion yet still get null.

Comment: That's unfortunately hard to help with. What do you get when you log `dataSnapshot.toString()`?